# Weird behavior on a test im desigining

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

This posted has been updated from a previous post a few hours earlier...

I am trying to make a multiple choice test for an RPG website. 
Their are 14 questions, and each one has 8 answers.

Each of the 8 answers corresponds to 1 of a set of 8 variables, upon submission the user who clicks radio buttons, ends up adding points to the proper variable.

At which point a comparison is run to spit out the proper results.

The problems I had earlier have been solved and so have been erased, but I didnt want to start a new thread on the same topic.

Current Problem:

I have pieced together  this code: (the full code will be below)

```
// Go through all questions and add +1 for each checked
// input with a value = "monk" 

$('#test').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($('input[name = answer]:checked').val() == "monk"){
            secondaryResults.mnk++;
        console.log(secondaryResults);
        }


    })
```

Now the above works perfectly, what doesnt work is if I try the same exact line of code but switiching up the value and variable++; The response I get is that it just adds the value to the first variable.

For example:

Question 1 : Answer = monk

Question 2 : Answer = monk

question 3:  Answer = cleric

question 4:  Answer = wizard

with this code I expected the console.log to spit out

monk:2

cleric:1

Wizard:1

instead it spits out monk:4

I've tried creating the same function just for a different variable (below you'll see the second attempt for the value/var berserker/ber) and attaching it to the same click event. I also tried putting it inside the .each() function as well as inside the first .on() function. I get the same results each time

So **question**: what would I need to include in the above section of code, to make the code:

1. Continue to count each individual occurence of a check for all 8 variables
2. Store the users score inside the object (shown below) for later use.

currently the code does this, but only for one input value/variable which is Monk- shortened to mnk in the object.

All Script:

```
$(window).load(function() { 

$(".intro").appendTo('#display_box');
var question = $(".question");
var questionPosition = -1;

var secondaryResults = {
    def:0,
    ber:0,
    mnk:0,
    rng:0,
    cle:0,
    thf:0,
    mge:0,
};

var primaryResults = {
    def:0,
    ber:0,
    mnk:0,
    rng:0,
    cle:0,
    thf:0,
    mge:0,
};



function clearBox(){
    $("#display_box").children().fadeOut(500).appendTo('#question_holding');
};



function cycle(){

    question.eq(questionPosition).fadeIn(500).appendTo("#display_box");
    $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);


}





    $('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition--;
    if (questionPosition <= -1) {questionPosition = 13};
    clearBox();
    cycle();





});





$('#rightarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition++;
    if (questionPosition > 13) { questionPosition = 0};
    clearBox();
    cycle();

    if($('input[name^="answer"]:checked').length > 13 ) {
        $("#submit").css('display', 'block');
    }




});
$('#test').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($('input[name = answer]:checked').val() == "monk"){
            secondaryResults.mnk++;
        console.log(secondaryResults);
        }


    })



});

$('#test').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($('input[name = answer]:checked').val() == "berserker"){
            secondaryResults.ber++;
        console.log(secondaryResults);
        }


    })


});

});
```

Comment: We have no idea what `secondaryResults` is or how it gets generated. Provide [mcve]

Comment: Also nothing shown related to how you are determining if radios checked to hide/show button. `if ($('input[class^="mnkA"]:checked')) ` will return true if any meet criteria... use `length` to match total number

Comment: added entire script file

Comment: Would help to create basic demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thank you, in the processing of creating the JS fiddle I realize that I had written the code inside another functio ( missed the endeing bracket) The function it was written inside is the function that compares all 14 questions to see if all are answered. 

Even though the event that triggered it was diffrerent ( clicking the submit button, not clicking the next question arrow) 

It still processed and compared. 

when I moved the submit code outside those brackets I got the behavior I expected!

Comment: Often a good reason for scaling down part of your code ... many times problem jumps out at you

Comment: Thank you Charlietfl I would not have caught it if I didnt go through my code slowly, for new readers of my updated problem, this marks the end of the comments for the older iteration of this thread.